# creating Default httpsClient leads to error in multipart request

Tags: java, android, httpclient, multipart

I am trying to execute a multipart request using the below function, but when I create the httpClient I get this exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime(8909): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE

I am using **httpclient-4.3.4** (imports are below as well)

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;


public static void uploadFile() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/img.jpg";
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("ip/myRestservice");

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addTextBody("field1", "yes", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
File file = new File(filepath);
builder.addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file.ext");
HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();

uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); use this

Comment: why? it does not return the same CloseableHttpClient